# Trace the IP address

Tags: ip, ipv4

I have created a web application using Django. While running someone entered the admin login and deleted the users. when checked in the access log of Nginx we found the IP address that actually did the attack. How can I trace the IP and find out who the person is?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the good, direct answers to your question, there's a lession to be learned here - or actually two:

1. secure admin access

   - use strong passwords or user certificates
   - limit access to admin interfaces to admin staff only
   - if the interface needs to be open on a public IP address limit access to public IPs you actually need
2. backup your data at least daily

   - data not backed up is not important

In short: be paranoid.

Comment: 3.  Ensure you test-restore your backups.  Untested backups are not backups. Just because the backup command said it was successful, it doesn't mean a thing.  Even when the restore program says it's successful, I am skeptical.  I do periodic audits and test runs.  I learned this very, very, expensively, a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  It is doubtful that you will be able to identify the person who did this.  You may get some hints that allow you to speculate, but it's not very likely you will find anything definite.

For example, if the address belongs to your internal network, that would be a good hint that the person is in your organization.  You might be able to identify the particular computer.

But if the address is a public address, your chances decrease considerably.  You might be able to tell what country and perhaps what city the person was in, but not much more than that.

As @jonathanjo points out, attackers can hide their true address.

Comment: Can you furthur help me?in this situation

Comment: IP addresses are not like phone numbers, because they can be temporarily assigned to computers.  So there isn't a way to identify a person.  If it was a typical home computer, the IP address is assigned by the person's ISP, and they won't give you that information.

Comment: I would just learn from your mistake and from now on make sure your databases are not accessible from the Internet, and that you use strong passwords to protect your data.

Comment: yeah i changed the passwords and i understand the thing you said

Comment: But i think that he will again try hacking tomorrow.How can i track him red handed?

Comment: You can't without a lot of effort, time and money.  And what would you do with that information anyway, especially if it's someone you don't know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84063/discussion-between-anish-tiwari-and-ron-trunk).

Answer (score 1):

In general, usually you can't find out the person.

To try to find out about a given IP address, the usual way is to start with the "whois" tools of a registry such as RIPE.

Just put the IP address into the search at the top of RIPE's web page: https://www.ripe.net/

Be aware that a miscreant is likely to be in another country, and indeed may have covered their tracks in any number of ways: that is to say, the address you have might be the address of another victim of the miscreants.

Comment: Thank you @jonathanjo for hrlping me out. I found out that the ip is public and from my same city

Answer (score 0):

If you have his IP address try locating his location or WHOIS IP from http://whatismyip.live and contact the respective ISP.

Answer (score 0):

whois will tell you the owner of the IP block.

You can (and probablly should) report the incident to the abuse contact of the IP block owner, but they may not do anything about it.

The problem is even if the source computer is found it will most likely just be a compromised machine. Tracing an attack back through the web of compromised machines to the individual that did it is very difficult even for a well-resourced law enforcement agency and basically impossible for normal people.